# Run script from home/bin that does a source command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script, say "script1.sh", that calls `source` on another script.  I'd like to have script1.sh in the `~/bin` folder so I can execute it from anywhere without having to type full path.

But of course executing it will not cause `source` to perform as desired.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: If you source the other script with it's full path, it'll work as expected, right?

Comment: @mtak _In_ scrip1.sh: `source ~/path/to/file/script2.sh`, no, once scrip1.sh exits the environment vars set/exported in script2.sh are not properly set

Comment: The `source` command searches `$PATH` to find files without directories (no `/` in name), **but** (1) unless `bash` has the POSIX-compliant flag set the current directory will be searched; and (2) non-executable files will be found and run, so a non-executable file of the same name as you want will be run if it's found first in the `$PATH` directory order.

Comment: In reply to your comment to @mtak, any variables set in `source script2.sh` will be available in `script1.sh`, but will not be available in the calling shell unless `script1.sh` is also invoked with `source`.

Comment: @AFH I see now it does, but it doesn't allow tab-complete of what's in bin.  Do you know of any way to get that to happen?  Aside from that this may be the solution I'll use. Thanks.

Comment: You simply insert  `complete -c . source` in `.bashrc` in order to make the `.` and `source` commands search `$PATH` for all possible completions, but it won't search the current directory and it won't find non-executables, even though `.` and `source` will invoke a non-executable in `$PATH`. You can set up your own completion lists for specific commands, but it's very complex and I've never done it (start [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html) if you want to pursue it). By the way, my `.bashrc` includes `complete -c man`, which I find useful.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your comment on the other script, I assume you want to set env vars in script2.sh and have them still valid once script1.sh finishes running.

I think the top answer from this stackoverflow question will give you what you are looking for:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618071/can-i-export-a-variable-to-the-environment-from-a-bash-script-without-sourcing-i#16619261

Answer (score 0):

Looking at my own scripts, two variations based on `$0` being the fully resolved name of the invoked script:

1. General case: get the directory of the current script, and use it to locate the source script:

   ```
   . $(dirname $0)/sourcedscript
   ```
2. With adequate naming conventions (script `foobar` can be customized by editing a `foobar-setup` script:

   ```
   . $0-setup
   ```